# Parsing nested json with Retrofit at Android

Tags: java, android, json, retrofit2, android-json

I'm using `retrofit` at my android application. At my webapi, there is a nested json result which i need to parse. Not nested ones are fine, but when i encountered nested one, it seems i can't parse them.

This is my json example. I've shortened it a bit but all same. 
When i executed call method, it just bypassing onResponse or onFailure. 
I'm thinking i made a mistake at my class file but i cant figure out what or how.

> JSON:

```
[
    {
        "name": "All joined for mobile",
        "selectedOnes": [
            "1",
            "2"
        ],
        "lines": [
            {
                "details": "",
                "cancelDetails": null,
                "isCancel": null,
                "hours": [
                    {
                        "arrivalTime": "",
                        "departTime": "07:15:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "arrivalTime": "07:30:00",
                        "departTime": ""
                    }
                ]
            },
            {
                "details": "",
                "cancelDetails": null,
                "isCancel": null,
                "hours": [
                    {
                        "arrivalTime": "",
                        "departTime": "07:30:00"
                    },
                    {
                        "arrivalTime": "07:45:00",
                        "departTime": ""
                    }
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

> ParsedJsonClass.java:

```
public class ParsedJsonClass {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;

    @SerializedName("selectedOnes")
    @Expose
    private List<String> selectedOnes = null;

    @SerializedName("lines")
    @Expose
    private List<lines> lines = null;

    public class lines {

        @SerializedName("details")
        @Expose
        private String details;

        @SerializedName("cancelDetails")
        @Expose
        private Object cancelDetails;

        @SerializedName("isCancel")
        @Expose
        private Object isCancel;

        @SerializedName("hours")
        @Expose
        private List<hours> hours = null;

        public class hours {

            @SerializedName("arrivalTime")
            @Expose
            private String arrivalTime;

            @SerializedName("departTime")
            @Expose
            private String departTime;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: post your deserialization code (onReceive, onFailure, etc). Also the main json is an array (starts with `[` and ends with `]`), in case you didn't take that into account

Comment: its null at response.body, Yes I know that. Its already an array but that is shown at postman. there is more hours below, i just posted two of them.

Comment: looks fine to me, but why do you put SerializedName and Expose everywhere? try to getting rid of all of them. And maybe dont null any declaration, that maybe throws off the Converter, by the way, which are you using? GSON? Get rid of the extra surrounding array at you're REST API or account for it somehow

Comment: SerializedName's for JSON names, expose's came with when i generate class at pojo